# Warning: Failed to set final value of List-Unsubscribe

Tags: civimail

I'm running civiCRM  v5.70.1 under Joomla 3.10.12.
Last week I enabled Settings - CiviMail: Unsubscribe Methods HTTP(S) One-Click
On the next scheduled mailing, I noticed it completed with zero sends.
civicrm error log reported: [warning] Failed to set final value of List-Unsubscribe

Anyone have some insight into why this would occur?

Comment: What is your "verp separator" at `civicrm/admin/mail?reset=1`? You can also try debugging the value of `$params['List-Unsubscribe']` at CRM/Mailing/Service/ListUnsubscribe.php line 48

Comment: My verp separator is set to a period ( . )
Debugging the value of $params is beyond my pay grade, not sure how I'd do that...